# Memory efficient structure for membership checking without false positive

Tags: bigdata, scalability

The initial task can be described like this:
I have a requirement to deduplicate HUGE list(potentially billions of items) without storing the original items - it's simply unaffordable

All I need to know is answer to the question "Has my system ever seen this element before?"

The most close data structure I was able to find so far is a bloom filter, but it has false positives which better to avoid in my task as it results in data loss

For example providing I account to store at least 2^32 items, with positive error rate of just 1%(which means 1% of all urls won't be visited) I would need at least

```
n = 4,294,967,296, p = 0.01 (1 in 100) → m = 41,167,512,262 (4.79GB), k = 7
```

4.79GB of memory...

The task itself is a high scale web crawler, so I need to keep track of already visited urls(or sha1 hashes of this urls)

Any help is welcome

Thanks!

Comment: The only way I currently see is using bigger bloom filter with more acceptable error rate like 1 per million and store the whole filter on ssd storage(it can be easily over 1TB nowdays for affordable price while having great random read/write speed). This at least looks like an implementable approach. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For web crawler scale why not use a distributed database like Apache Cassandra? Lookups on indexes are efficient and no false positives.

Comment: Sounds like a good deal, currently reviewing what it offers and it seems to be a perfect fit for this particular task. Is there any idea how much disk space would it take to store 1 billion of 20 bytes hashes inside a set? My dumb estimate would be ~20gb, am I close enough?

Comment: Disk space is cheap. Not too sure why this would be a concern. See here for estimating sizes. http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningUserData_t.html

Comment: Thank you very much @init-random for pointing me to cassandra - a _perfect_ fit